# Mongo DB chained query

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and as I wonder if a chained query like the following is possible(somewhat like a join):

```
db.places.insert({
"_id": original_id
"place_name": "Broadway Center"
"url": "bc.example.net"})

db.people.insert({
"name": "Erin"
"places_id": original_id
"url":  "bc.example.net/Erin"})
```

So given a place name string, I want to select the people associated with that place.
But the people collection only reference the place id, not the place name.

Comment: MongoDB HAS NO JOINS...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use joins in MongoDB.

The idiomatic solution is retrieve all `place_ids` for that `place_name` from your places collection and then use the `place_ids` to query in your people collection.

Another option is keeping, for example, `places` in `people` collection (this makes more sense to me than `people` inside `places` collection but, of course, it depends on your domain). But then you have to take into account that in case that only one place changes, you have to change all people documents sharing a specific place. If people and places are in separate collections this doesn't happen so it depends on if we have static data or not and on if we want to optimize searches or updates.

Comment: or put the people in the places and store them in one collection, or the places in the people, or both, know your queries upfront! denormalization is worth the performance gain.

Comment: That's right but then if you keep, for example, places in people collection, you have to change all people documents sharing a specific place if only one place changes. If they are in separate collections this doesn't happen. So it depends on if we have static data or not and on if we want to optimize searches or updates.